# Can't find DMT mode resolution for VNC

Tags: vnc, screen

After last update If I try to set screen resolution for my VNC connection, I can't see too DMT mode options.
Any idea?

Comment: What is 'DMT mode'?

Comment: Please add more info to this question. It will be hard for us to answer if it is that short. Add details that answers our questions like "What version?" or "What is DMT mode?" Please add as much info about your answer as you can.

About your question, What model are you using? Did you try reinstalling Raspberry Pi OS?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for delay. I've solved the issue by means a clean installation of my Raspberry's OS. Now I can set VNC's resolution without issue. No DMT problem too. Thanks to all